# PHP Mysql query multiple items

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have this part of code:

```
resultrights = $conn->query("SELECT userid, page FROM pagerights WHERE     userid = '" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "'");

while ($rowrightss = $resultrights->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $rowrightss['page']."<br>";
}
```

This works. It just echoes the numbers 
    1
    2
    3
    5
Perfectly fine.

Now, I want to select a few buttons based on that numbers. They are button numbers, declared else in the DB.

Somewhere later I have this:

```
<?php
$i = 0;

$result = $conn->query("select pagenumber, pagetitle from pages WHERE pagenumber = '" . $_SESSION['assignedpage'] . "'");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo '<table cellpadding="20">';


while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($id, $name);
              $id = $row['pagenumber'];
              $name = $row['pagetitle']; 
              $i++;
//if this is first value in row, create new row
if ($i % 3 == 1) {
    echo "<tr>";
}
echo '<td><button1 id="groteknop" class="btn-state state-start" onclick="Switchf();"><i id="knopje" class="icon icon-start"></i></button1></td>';
//if this is third value in row, end row
if ($i % 3 == 0) {
    echo "</tr>";
}
}
//if the counter is not divisible by 3, we have an open row
$spacercells = 3 - ($i % 3);
if ($spacercells < 3) {
for ($j=1; $j<=$spacercells; $j++) {
    echo "<td></td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</select>";
$conn->close();
?>
```

What I am trying to achieve, is instead of the pagenumber = the session value assigned page, I want to select all buttons from the result of the query before. Endresult: I want to display button 1, 2, 3, 5. This numbers are coming from the first query. So when these numbers change, and they do, because they are selected based on userid, I want to display the result of that query.

How can I get that working?

Comment: what do you want to use instead of session?I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: @yafater I edited it a little.

Comment: ok.you have multiple value instead of session that is array

Comment: Right now it selects the button based on the " . $_SESSION['assignedpage'] . ". I want it to select them based on the other query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this query

```
     select pagenumber, pagetitle from pages WHERE pagenumber in 
         (SELECT  page FROM pagerights WHERE  userid = '" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "')
```

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: It works, and does exactly what I want. Thank you for this.

Comment: I am so sorry I didn't. I accepted it almost a year late, but I did :) @yafater

Comment: oh! Thank you @MarkSchrik

Answer (score 0):

To me this seems a task for an [inner join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html), which would join `pagerights` table with the `pages` table. If I understood your question correctly, then `pagerights.page` should match `page.pagenumber`.

```
SELECT page.pagenumber, page.pagetitle FROM pagerights
INNER JOIN page ON pagerights.page=page.pagenumber 
WHERE userid=...
```

Substitute the user id from session in the place of `...` in the query. this way you need to run only a single query.

Comment: You're 100% correct about the page rights.page matches page.pagenumber. I am gonna test this right away!

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/selectview.php on line 56

Comment: Man, do some error handling and get the underlying sql error message! Also, provide the actual code you tried to run, do not just paste an error message without any context, this is absolutely not helpful!

Comment: I wrote `page` instead of `pages` as table name. I hope, you did correct that.